# Textfile static metric value from Prometheus as instance legend for Grafana alerts?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, alert, promql, grafana-alerts

Currently, I have setup instances in our cluster to emit metrics over Prometheus, including a static metric using a textfile collector, which looks like this:

```
prod_server{id="12345"} 1
```

These metrics help identify the instance with IDs that we use throughout our infrastructure, rather than their IP addresses. Currently, I have an alert setup in Grafana Alerts that uses the following query to get memory usage per instance:

```
100 - (sum by (instance) (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes)) * 100
```

This results in Grafana retrieving memory usage percentage per instance, and labelling them by their IP addresses, such as `instance=10.10.0.1`, `instance=10.10.0.2` and so on.

My question is, is there a way to modify these labels/legends such that instead of the IP addresses, the custom textfile collector metric is used to label the instances instead?

Thank you!

Comment: In your exact case: `(100 - (sum by (instance) (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes)) * 100) * on(instance) group_left(id) prod_server`

Comment: A better way would be to use [relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) to either add a new label with human-readable value, or modify instance value.

Comment: @anemyte, I agree that relabeling a valid alternative. But it's not always a **better** way. For example, if you have dynamic instances and auto-discovery of targets, relabeling is not very obvious or simple to perform.